# Set window's default location on a user screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows Form Application.I want that when the application will run my window will always just on Taskbar and on the Right side means on the bottom-right of a user screen.It doesn't matter what is a user screen resolution is.So how can i do that ???

Comment: By 'Taskbar on the right side' you mean on the notification area?

Comment: **Above** the task bar or **on top of** (overlap) the task bar? Also note that the task bar does **not** always stays on the bottom.

Comment: Do you just want one of those popup notification balloons, or is this a form that will be there all the time?

Comment: Top of the notification area...so that my window remain up of the taskbar

Comment: @user2029069 still unclear... overlap or not? Also as I stated that the task bar could be on the top side of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build on [MeNoMore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14701228/80274), to make your form show up in the bottom right corner of the primary screen (the screen with the task bar is usually the primary screen) you would set the following in the constructor of your form.

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width,
                          Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers will not work. You have to do **two** things:

1. Set form's `StartPosition` to `Manual`
2. Set form's `Location` to what point you want

E.g. inside form's constructor:

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width,
                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
Form1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that that is the top left corner of the form, you will need to read the screen resolution via `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` or similar and do the math.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ur right, he will still need to consider the resolution

Comment: But user resolution may vary. so how can i relatively give it position. It will possible if i can use percentage for x and y .

Comment: You will have to calculate this according to your forms width and hight, take alook at Scott Chamberlain answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [Form.StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property

Answer (score 0):

You use the WinTaskBar component for considering other factors on a desktop/screen.

```
    [DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);
```

It will let you control the positions (left & top).

Example:

```
formStartLeft = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width;
formStartTop = taskBarHeight + Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```